# I can't clear a form with .reset()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a form where the user inputs items onto a text box and when they hit "enter" it puts the text into a list. However I also want to clear what they'd put into the form right after they hit enter (sorta like skype). here's my jquery code.

```
$('#inputpnote').keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        var $pnote = document.getElementById("inputpnote").value;
        if ($pnote.length > 0) {
            $("#pnotes-list").append("<div class='pnote-list'><li>" + $pnote + "</li></div>");
            $pnote.reset();
        }
    }

});
```

`#inputpnote` is the text form and `#pnotes-list` is where I'm putting the text they'd typed.

help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: jquery does not have a `.reset()` method, it is a DOM element function

Comment: Looks like you're calling `reset` on the input's value, which is not a valid action. you may call `reset` function of your form element if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `#inputpnote` isn't the form ID, but a field ID, maybe you'll need to use `val`:

```
$('#inputpnote').val('');
```

Comment: ;) Nice, glad to help